# htaccess - two rewrites with same folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So i'm trying to set two different rewriting with the same folder. Here's what i want to do...

These URL

> http://www.mywebsite.com/tshirts_bands
>   http://www.mywebsite.com/tshirts_bands/some_band_name
>   http://www.mywebsite.com/tshirts_bands/another_band

would use the following files:

> http://www.mywebsite.com/bands.php
>   http://www.mywebsite.com/bands.php?band=some_band_name
>   http://www.mywebsite.com/bands.php?band=another_band

Here's what i tried:

```
RewriteRule ^tshirts_bands$ /bands.php [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^tshirts_bands/([^.]+)$ /bands.php?band=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

as asked, here's my full htaccess:

```
    ErrorDocument 404 /404.php 

RewriteEngine On
# Matching any of 3 domains without www, and no subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(ni-dieu-ni-maitre|no-gods-no-masters|ni-dios-ni-amo)\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]



RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^images/([^/]+)_([^/]+)_([^/]+)/([^.]+)\.png$ /image_zoom.php?img=$1&color=$2&tshirt=$3&keywords=$4 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^images_bestsellers/([^/]+)_([^/]+)_([^/]+)/([^.]+)\.png$ /image_bestseller.php?img=$1&color=$2&tshirt=$3&keywords=$4 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^images_minis/([^/]+)/([^.]+)\.png$ /image_cache.php?a=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^images_minis_t/([^/]+)/([^.]+)\.png$ /image_mini.php?a=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^A-([0-9]+)/([^.]+)$ /tshirt.php?t=t-shirt-A$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^bands_tshirts/([^/]+)/([^.]+)\.png$ /image_design.php?design=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

# RewriteRule ^tshirts_bands$ /bands.php [L,QSA,NC]
# RewriteRule ^tshirts_bands/([^.]+)$ /bands.php?band=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/tshirts_bands/?([^/]*)?/?   [NC]
RewriteRule .*    bands.php?band=%1  [L]


<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: So what happens when you enter `http://www.mywebsite.com/tshirts_bands` in your browser? Also can you post your complete .htaccess?

Comment: It works with the URL you posted, but doesn't work with a band name. I updated the post with the complete htaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/tshirts_bands/?([^/]*)?/?   [NC]
RewriteRule .*    bands.php?band=%1  [L]
```

---

**Update**

I've tested with some scenario:

```
<?php //bands.php (testbox)
var_dump($_GET);
```

And here my results

```
//http://test.dev/tshirts_bands
//http://test.dev/tshirts_bands/

array (size=1)
  'band' => string '' (length=0)

//http://test.dev/tshirts_bands/RedHotChiliPeppers

array (size=1)
  'band' => string 'RedHotChiliPeppers' (length=18)

//http://test.dev/tshirts_bands/Slipknot

array (size=1)
  'band' => string 'Slipknot' (length=8)
```

---

**Update2**
your .htaccess must looks like the code below:

```
####
# error handling
####
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php 

####
# header handling
####
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>

####
# url rewriting
####
RewriteEngine On

# Matching any of 3 domains without www, and no subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(ni-dieu-ni-maitre|no-gods-no-masters|ni-dios-ni-amo)\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^images/([^/]+)_([^/]+)_([^/]+)/([^.]+)\.png$ /image_zoom.php?img=$1&color=$2&tshirt=$3&keywords=$4 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^images_bestsellers/([^/]+)_([^/]+)_([^/]+)/([^.]+)\.png$ /image_bestseller.php?img=$1&color=$2&tshirt=$3&keywords=$4 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^images_minis/([^/]+)/([^.]+)\.png$ /image_cache.php?a=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^images_minis_t/([^/]+)/([^.]+)\.png$ /image_mini.php?a=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^A-([0-9]+)/([^.]+)$ /tshirt.php?t=t-shirt-A$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^bands_tshirts/([^/]+)/([^.]+)\.png$ /image_design.php?design=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

# RewriteRule ^tshirts_bands$ /bands.php [L,QSA,NC]
# RewriteRule ^tshirts_bands/([^.]+)$ /bands.php?band=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/tshirts_bands/?([^/]*)?/?   [NC]
RewriteRule .*    bands.php?band=%1  [L]
```

Comment: @libertaire i forgot two sign in the rule. now i've tested.

Comment: still doesn't work for me, maybe it is a problem with my htaccess ? i just updated the post with my full htaccess file

Comment: you have three times `RewriteEngine on` in the .htaccess - i make another update in my answer

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time !! It's working now, and my htaccess is much more clear !

Comment: Your welcome, hope your target is a little closer :)